# Stop navigation for ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, single-page-application, singlepage

I'm writing an application that has some mixed single-page/multi-page aspects.

Let's say the menu is something like:

About Us | Blog

The **About Us** link is a regular `<a href="about-us.html">` link which navigates away from the current page when clicked.

The **Blog** link is a javascript link which makes an AJAX call and changes the current page to the blog by dynamically writing in some new HTML.

If the user clicks the **About Us** link and then changes their mind and clicks the **Blog** link, I want to cancel the navigation to "about-us.html".  What I'm experiencing now is sometimes the about us page takes some time to load and the blog loads and displays first, but because the browser is already requesting the about us page, when that request catches up, the page changes. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you try window.stop() from inside your ajax call. I hope, it should not interfere with the ajax request and just stop the refresh.

Comment: If at all this suffices, you may be interested in doing something special for IE, as expected: document.execCommand("Stop");

Comment: @RajatSharma This seems to work perfectly. Thank you! Please make it into an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try window.stop() from inside your ajax call. For IE you will have to use document.execCommand("Stop");